# Using Angular and Node Express CSRF with Redis Session, how to reset session info and CSRF after session expiring?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, session, express, redis

I am running Express and NodeJS as a backend for an angular frontend.  I'm using RedisStore for the sessions.  Using [this blog article](http://mircozeiss.com/using-csrf-with-express-and-angular/), I was able to come up with the following code:

```
app.use express.cookieParser(config.session.signed)
app.use express.session( {
  secret: config.session.secret,
  cookie: config.session.cookie,
  store: new RedisStore({
    client: client
  })
} )

app.use express.csrf()
app.use (req, res, next) ->
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.session._csrf)
  next()

app.use passport.initialize()
app.use passport.session({})
```

Everything works swimmingly until the redis session expires (I have this set for two hours in my config).  After the session expires, I get the forbidden error:

```
Error: Forbidden
    at Object.exports.error (/code/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:62:13)
    ...
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to catch this error and reset the RedisSession (and the CSRF token), and as a result, the single page angular frontend just appears dead and it requires a page refresh to grab a new session and revive things.

Anyone else run into this issue?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you figure this out? Running into this as well...

Comment: Well, never got an answer on how to properly catch the error in Node, but in the meantime, I'm catching the error in my angular frontend and calling `$route.reload()` to update the page and grab a new cookie.  It's just a little less than ideal because in the case of a login event, I have to catch the error, reload the route, and then resend the request in order to keep the user experience seamless.  But it does work.

Answer (score 1):

You could *touch* the session, so it doesn't expire...

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  if ('HEAD' === req.method || 'OPTIONS' === req.method) return next();

  req.session._garbage = new Date()
  req.session.touch()
  next();
});
```

So every time your SPA POSTs or GETs to any '/api/...' path, for example, your session expiration can get postponed...

Actually, in our latest project, we don't use `express.csrf()` anymore, but some form of this:

```
if('GET' isnt req.method)
  token = (req.body and req.body._csrf) or (req.query and req.query._csrf) or (req.headers["x-csrf-token"]) or (req.headers["x-xsrf-token"])
  if token isnt req.session._csrfSecret
    return res.json 403, 'action forbidden: invalid application status, please refresh'
else
  unless req.session._csrfSecret
    req.session._csrfSecret = cryptos.long_token()

req.session.touch()
```